# jQuery.animate() - click event does not fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, jquery-animate

When using `.animate()` while changing `top`/`left`, the click event does not seem to fire. For example:

```
<div style="width: 640px; height: 480px; position: relative;">
<div id="child" onclick="alert('ok')" style="position: relative;">Some text</div>
</div>
```

With script something like:

```
$('#child').animate({ top: 200, left: 200 }, 2000);
```

When you click the div, you do not see an alert -- you must wait for the element to stop moving first.
Is there any way to fix this problem? :(

EDIT: My example is not accurate to my problem. Sorry guys! Thanks for the quick answers.

EDIT: An updated example is here, with the problem reproduced: http://jsfiddle.net/M9udv/8/
Also I am using the latest Chrome.

EDIT again: OK, I am using `jquery.live("click", function() {});` and it seems to work when I also include `$(targ).stop(true);` within the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it does work however the wire-frame around the element is quite small and difficult to click when it's moving. I made an example of this working (and tested in a few different browsers) with some padding to make the element easier to click: http://jsfiddle.net/M9udv/

Comment: OK, perhaps my example is not very good. I have updated the jsfiddle thing but not sure how to get jquery's $(function()); to fire in it.

Comment: I get this error in your jsfiddle: `window.dictionary.entries[word4Index] is undefined`. However if the boxes are supposed to animate around and explode on click, it worked on my end.

Answer (score 1):

It does work.
Probably, because it's animated, you have a hard time clicking on the actual element (which is rather small).
Take a look here : http://jsfiddle.net/GA5Re/

Comment: You are correct. Thanks for you answer -- a reproduction is here: http://jsfiddle.net/M9udv/8/

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply move the alert into your jQuery code with:

```
$('#child').click(function(){
alert('ok');
$(this).animate({ top: 200, left: 200 }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry perhaps I was not very specific. Assume that something other than clicking the element has triggered the animate() movement. Now, while it is already moving, if you try to click it, the event does not fire.

Comment: Well in that case it would appear your element is moving too fast to be clicked - as it's only text it's unlikely you'd be very accurate, as the other answers mentioned.